# При обращении к словарю по ключу он думает что обращение идет по индексу

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
VIP_BONUS = {1: (40000, 200),
             2: (30000, 150),
             3: (20000, 100),
             4: (10000, 50),
             5: (4000, 30)},

BONUS_DATA = VIP_BONUS[5]
```

OUT:

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

Вопрос, как обратиться по ключу к указанному словарю?

Comment: Убрать запятую после последней '}'?

Comment: @strawdog как же я её не заметил, спасибо)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

замените:

```
VIP_BONUS = {1: (40000, 200),
             2: (30000, 150),
             3: (20000, 100),
             4: (10000, 50),
             5: (4000, 30)},  # <-- запятая после "}" превращает VIP_BONUS в кортеж с единственным элементом - словарем
```

на:

```
VIP_BONUS = {1: (40000, 200),
             2: (30000, 150),
             3: (20000, 100),
             4: (10000, 50),
             5: (4000, 30)}
```

Пояснение: если после переменной поставить запятую, то вместо скалярного значения получится кортеж:

```
a = 1,
print(type(a))
>>> <class 'tuple'>
```

Comment: на секунду раньше

Comment: @Danis, вы были раньше на целых две секунды )

Answer (score 3):

у вас после `}` стоит запятая, из-за этого в переменную записывается не словарь, а кортеж с одним элементом

```
VIP_BONUS = {1: (40000, 200),
             2: (30000, 150),
             3: (20000, 100),
             4: (10000, 50),
             5: (4000, 30)}
```